# Laravel doesnt see my package

Tags: php, laravel

Create a package (shopping cart) for my laravel app. Got a service provider - `CartServiceProvider`, belongs to namespace `Alexxosipov\Cart`.

```
<?php

namespace Alexxosipov\Cart;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart as Cart;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {

    }

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('cart', function() {
            return new Cart();
        });
    }
}
```

Then, I create new namespace in root `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Alexxosipov\\Сart\\": "packages/alexxosipov/cart/src"
        }
    }
```

And I add it to array `providers` in `app.php`: 
`Alexxosipov\Cart\CartServiceProvider::class,`

And make `composer dump-autoload`. But I still have an error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Alexxosipov\Cart\CartServiceProvider' not found
```

Where did I go wrong?

UPD: screenshot of my file system
[image]

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to the src path: `packages/alexxosipov/cart/src/`, then dump the autoload again.

Comment: Can you tell me what the file path to your `CartServiceProvider` class is, from your `src` directory?

Comment: @Cryode already tried to do, still got an error, nothing changes

Comment: @Jonathon yes, added screenshot to question, where you can see my files

Comment: Is this problem happening on your local Windows development environment, or elsewhere?

Comment: Have you done a `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: @Cryode openserver, local. Windows 7.

Comment: @Jonathon yes, wrote it in my question

Comment: Maybe this is the reason: I create a new folder (`larashop.loc`) in `domains` directory, then I redirect all requests from `larashop.loc`to `larashop.loc/public` folder. But there's no any relationships between my laravel app and local environment

Comment: Do you added the class to `config/app.php` in `providers`?

Comment: @kip yes, of course. Wrote about it in question

Comment: I think that is problem of `composer`, check this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fatal-error-class-illuminatefoundationapplication-not-found-in-pathtoprojectbootstrapappphp-on-line-14?page=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"Alexxosipov\\": "packages/alexxosipov/"
```

Instead of:

```
"Alexxosipov\\Сart\\": "packages/alexxosipov/cart/"
```

Then... save your serviceProvider class inside of "packages/alexxosipov/cart/", run `compose dumpautoload` command and update your service provider:

```
<?php

namespace Alexxosipov\Cart;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Alexxosipov\Cart\Cart as Cart;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {}

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('cart', function() {
            return new Cart();
        });
    }
}
```

This will must be work fine.

Comment: yes, it's work, thanks! But what should I do to follow the standart and place all files inside the `src` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this..
Adding the **extra** key value section on the composer.json file for you package helps with Laravel Class Auto Discovery. https://laravel-news.com/package-auto-discovery

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Folder\\SubFolder\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Folder\\SubFolder\\ClassNameServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Nickname": "Folder\\SubFolder\\Facades\\ClassName"
            }
        }
    }
```